# Understanding why PHP does not load an extension

Tags: php, memcached

I've compiled PHP from source (5.5.7), as well as the memcached extension (2.2.0). I've installed memcached and the extension is correctly installed in `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212` (there is the memcached.so file) and my `php -i` tells me that the extension directory is correct : `extension_dir => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212`

PHP runs correctly simple files, but when I load an app using memcached, the PHP error log file tells me only `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found` but I have no more details.

When I run `php -m`, there is no `memcached` module listed.

How can I find out why memcached is not loaded by PHP ?

Comment: You need to add the loading of the module to the `php.ini` file.

Comment: Thanks. Have been looking for it for hours and didn't understand why mods-available was not used (there is a memcached.conf file in there, with the correct `extension=` string

Answer (score 1):

For the record, it's not enough that there is a `memcached.so` file in the `extension_dir` of PHP. PHP also needs to extension to be explicitly loaded in the php.init file.
Solved it with the following command
`echo 'extension=memcache.so' >> /usr/local/lib/php.ini`